# page level watchpoints in gdb

Tags: debugging, macos, memory, gdb

Is there anyway in GDB to put a memory watchpoints on page level?
I want to break on first access to a page, this access can be anywhere on that page, so i can't put a normal memory watchpoints - since I don't know the address -
Also, is there anyway to change the page protection of memory page in GDB ( say change from r/w to no access ), this way any access to that page will cause an A/V and I can catch it
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. But a bit of arranging with mprotect and sigaction can give you the same effect.